# Can't boot TAILS virtual nachine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, tails-os

I've downloaded TAILS and when I boot everything goes normally until it fully boots up, at which point it shows the desktop for a second and then says "Uh Oh! An error has occured" or something similar.

I've tried going to the other consoles with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and all of them ask for a username and password which I can't find after looking up and was never asked to enter. I'm using VirtualBox on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

When booting tails i think there is option "more" where you can choose a root password for the session. Try to get a console and run dmesg.

Comment: You can select a root password but im not sure what the username is. I tried root which didnt work and other than that im not sure what to do.

Comment: @fabtasticwill root is the username for root. So if you have set a root password then you should use that with root.

Comment: root doesnt work as a username with the password I selected. It just says login incorrect.

Comment: Maybe root is disabled, then you login with normal user and then "sudo -i" in a terminal.

Comment: The issue is that I cant login